# Cannot scroll horizontally in Android 2.2, 2.3.3 with jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 or 1.1.0; 2.3.3

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I cannot scroll horizontally in Android 2.2 and 2.3.3 versions.  I have confirmed this on the Android Emulator SDK 2.2 and 2.3.3 versions and an Android version 2.2 device.  I have scaling enabled and this is by design.  This is very frustrating and it's happening on one of the most common versions of the Android OS.  On the emulator, if I press my mouse down and try to scroll horizontally, I would say it works well-less than 1 out of 10 times.  It's as if the DOM is frozen.  I don't understand why this is happening.

Anybody have an answer and a solution?  I, and others, would greatly appreciate any feedback.  Thank you, again, for any help.

Comment: Please include some relevant code and any logcat errors. I can scroll horizontally with the code I have but I can't see your code...